# Adding JOIN for associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

My **Organization** class looks something like this:

```
has_many Students
```

My **Student** class looks like this:

```
has_many Klasses
belongs_to Organization
```

My **Klass** class looks like this:

```
some field named : price
scope :top_expensive_classes, joins(:students).order('price DESC')
belongs_to Student
```

And my query looks like this:

```
@results = Klass.top_expensive_classes.where(organization_id: params[:id]).limit(RESULT_SET_COUNT)
```

Notice that it starts with Klass,  so that's the problem because I am searching in the where class for organization_id but that is not in the Klass,  it is in Student class , so somehow I should introduce a join somewhere to fix this but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue is your associations are likely incorrect.

- A student has many classes
- A class has many students

but what you have is

- A student has many classes
- A class belongs to a single student

This doesn't really make sense (at least in any situation I've ever seen a class and student interact). You should be creating a many-to-many relationship instead of a one-to-many relationship between `Klass` and `Student`.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :klasses, through: :student_klasses
  has_many :student_klasses
end

class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: :student_klasses
  has_many :student_klasses
end

class StudentKlass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :klass
end
```

Once you have these correct associations in place, you need to call `.joins` on the `:students` association from the `Klass` class. You can do without the scope.

```
Klass.joins(:students).where("students.organization_id = ?", params[:id]).order('price DESC').limit(RESULT_SET_COUNT)
```

Read [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-a-single-association) on ActiveRecord Querying.

---

Here is the proof *(using the exact model definitions above)* that the ordering of the associations does **not** matter.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = Student.create(name: "Deefour")
  SQL (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "students" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:33:32 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Deefour"], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:33:32 UTC +00:00]]
=> #<Student id: 1, name: "Deefour", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:33:32", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:33:32">
irb(main):002:0> kk = []
=> []

irb(main):003:0> kk << Klass.create(title: "Klass 1")
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "klasses" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:06 UTC +00:00], ["title", "Klass 1"], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:06 UTC +00:00]]
=> [#<Klass id: 1, title: "Klass 1", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06">]

irb(main):004:0> kk << Klass.create(title: "Klass 2")
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "klasses" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:14 UTC +00:00], ["title", "Klass 2"], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:14 UTC +00:00]]
=> [#<Klass id: 1, title: "Klass 1", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06">, #<Klass id: 2, title: "Klass 2", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:14", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:14">]

irb(main):005:0> s.klasses = kk
  Klass Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" INNER JOIN "student_klasses" ON "klasses"."id" = "student_klasses"."klass_id" WHERE "student_klasses"."student_id" = ?  [["student_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "student_klasses" ("created_at", "klass_id", "student_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:29 UTC +00:00], ["klass_id", 1], ["student_id", 1], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:29 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "student_klasses" ("created_at", "klass_id", "student_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:29 UTC +00:00], ["klass_id", 2], ["student_id", 1], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Mar 2013 01:34:29 UTC +00:00]]
=> [#<Klass id: 1, title: "Klass 1", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:06">, #<Klass id: 2, title: "Klass 2", created_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:14", updated_at: "2013-03-08 01:34:14">]

irb(main):006:0> Student.first.klasses.map(&:id)
  Student Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" ORDER BY "students"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Klass Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" INNER JOIN "student_klasses" ON "klasses"."id" = "student_klasses"."klass_id" WHERE "student_klasses"."student_id" = ?  [["student_id", 1]]
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Do I still need to keep the Join the I have in that scope? Currently it says it can't find student table.  Do we have a syntax error somewhere? maybe something should be students instead of student?

Comment: it says "Association named 'students' was not found"

Comment: It looks like your associations are not exactly what they should be. I've updated my answer to help guide you.

Comment: Unless things have changed, your through relationships need to be defined AFTER the join relationship. The response here does not do that.

Comment: That's misinformation; the order does not matter.

Comment: @Robert proof from a test app added to the question for your convenience.